# Flutter: Fixed bottom button, central dynamic TextField that moves with keyboard popup

Tags: flutter-layout

Many variations of this question exist with solutions. I have been unable to find an adequate solution. Is it possible to fix a button at the bottom of the screen which the keyboard is allowed to overlay, but also moves the other text fields up?

I've attached a screenshot example

My current solution works, but the space between the textfield and the post button is a fixed SizedBox height. This shifts the post button around on different screen heights, which is hack.

Is there a way to do something similar to how an Expanded widget fills the empty space, but within a ListView? Expanded throws an error if parent is a ListView, and a parent of Flex would squeeze all the elements when the keyboard comes up.

Widget Layout: (super simplified)

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(//The photo boxes at top
      height: fixed,
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(),
      title: Container(child: TextField(),),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: screenHeight * 0.5 - 225
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: doThing
            child: Text('POST'),
            ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image: Screen example]

[image: Screen with keyboard]

Comment: try wrapping container(the photo boxes at top) which has fixed height, inside the Flexible() widget